# multidimensional dynamic matrix how can i create one?

Tags: c++

I am working in C++ on Ubuntu. I would like to know how to create a matrix with dynamic length?

I did this: `int matrix[12][]` but it's not working. The dimension for the columns will increase step by step in my code. Can someone show me the correct code in an example?

Comment: And please accept solutions to your previous questions.

Comment: *The dimension for the columns will increase step by step in my code* - does this mean you will get additional columns or additional rows?

Comment: do you want a 2D array, or do you want a matrix supporting matrix operations?

Answer (score 5):

```
int ** matrix;
matrix = new int* [rowcount];
for (int i = 0; i<rowcount; ++i)
{
   matrix[i] = new int[colcount]
}
```

To clean this up:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rowcount; ++i)
    delete [] matrix[i];
delete [] matrix;
```

Of course, when you use vectors, memory management is done automatically;

```
vector<vector<int> > matrix(rowcount, vector<int>(colcount));
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at the `boost ublas` library.  Its a numerical library - so has the operations you expect, such as matrix multiplication - but is c++-std like in the sense that it accepts arbitrary types via templates (like the `std::vector<Type>`).

You can find the documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm), with the matrix type [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm)

Pros:

- Its does your memory management for you,
- Its efficient
- It already has a host of algorithms for you to use (which you would have to re-write if you did a `vector<vector<type> >` matrix)

Cons:

- Adding rows and columns dynamically is not possible - you have to copy the entire matrix into a new, larger matrix.

Comment: +1 because `boost::ublas` is very useful, but I get a feeling OP wants matrices that change in size dynamically.

Comment: Oh, yes, I missed that part of the question

Answer (score 1):

I may use `vector`.

```
typedef std::vector< std::vector<int> > Matrix;
Matrix matrix;
matrix.resize(12); // 12 rows.
// Add one more coulmn
for ( Matrix::iterator iter = matrix.begin(); iter != matrix.end(); ++iter )
  (*iter).push_back(new_column_value);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number of columns changes in the course of your program, but the number of rows does not (this is how I read your question), then you should represent your matrix as [column-major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order). This means, the first index should represent columns, and the second index should represent rows. Then, represent your matrix as `std::vector< std::vector<int> >`. Now, if you want to add a column, you just add another vector. If you stored the matrix row-major, you would have to resize all the inner vectors to add an additional column.

If you want to use the indeces row-major anyway (because that is the convention), you can wrap the matrix in a class to switch the indices.

Answer (score 0):

You can to use [Vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)  for this purpose.

Comment: could you please give me an example?

Comment: `Vector <Vector(int)> matrix;` -  This will first create a 1-D vector, and then create another vector of this 1-D vector, thus in all, this will work as a dynamic 2D matrix

Answer (score 0):

the simpliest way to create matrix which dynamically change its size would be something derived from   `vector<vector<int> >` you should add some functions about resizing, because if you add new row to you matrix vector won't add columns automatically, and it will be what you need.

```
class myMatrix:public vector<vector<int> >
{
...
bool resize(int x, int y)
{
   resize(x);
   for(vector<vector<int> >::iterator iter = begin(); iter !=end(); ++iter)
   (*iter).resize(y);
}
}
```

Comment: -1: Never derive from STL class. STL classes usually has no virtual destructor and has special memory management (allocators).

Comment: No additional memory allocated here, all data manipulation is done by standard functions of class, so here is no harm. It's like saying "Do not use c++ it may leak memory"

Comment: C++ makes a clear distinction between classes that are meant to serve as base classes (e.g., they have a virtual dtor, pure virtual member functions, protected members etc.) and concrete classes that aren't meant to serve as base classes. These include STL containers and std::string. [The ANSI/ISO C++ Professional Programmer's Handbook](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0789720221)